# Strange header alignment while importing CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file, and when I look at data in jupyter notebook looks like this

```
group1,group2
50 - 150T,0
38 aH,0
33-10Ik,0
THAI,0
TO,0
STYLE,0
EDITOR,0
NORMAL,0
DIABETIC,0
```

I read the data

```
ds1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jupyterwork\\data.csv',index_col=0)
```

It looks like this, if I try to rename group1 to "#ds1.columns.values[0] = "col1"" then group2 is being changed to col1 instead of group1.

[image]

Comment: You explicitly import *group1* as the index not as a column.

Comment: Right.,  The index header is rendered differently.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I want to add group1 column to another dataframe what is the best way to do that?

Comment: `ds1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jupyterwork\\data.csv', usecols=[0])` & `ds2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\jupyterwork\\data.csv', usecols=[1])`